# upgrade multi instace web application installer

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Can i upgrade multi instance web application installer?

I could easily achieve multiinstance web application deployment, but when I changed `ProductVersion` since the `ProductCode` (guid) remains same in other instances I am getting the following error in log:

> MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.

Followed the below link for multi instance: http://ysdevlog.blogspot.in/2011/08/revisited-multiple-instance.html

```
<InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
  <Instance Id="I00" ProductCode="{GUID-HERE-4E6D-B26B-AA7EAFAF526B}" ProductName="TelStrat"/>
  <Instance Id="I01" ProductCode="{GUID-HERE-45A9-A703-5F01FE83380F}" ProductName="TelStrat1"/>
  <Instance Id="I02" ProductCode="{GUID-HERE-471E-9A00-8756C12F358F}" ProductName="TelStrat2"/>
</InstanceTransforms>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ProductCode` **must** be updated to be able to do major upgrades. You need to update the `ProductCode` in all the multi-instance transforms.